# How do President-elects and Vice-Presidents elects travel?

Tags: united-states, president, political-transitions

Biden and Harris are travelling to Georgia tonight to campaign for both democratic candidates in the Georgia runoffs.

How do they travel to get there? Given that Trump and Pence are still the incumbent President and Vice President respectively, Air Force 1 and ‘the beast’ is reserved for them. So how does the new coming administration get there?

My more broad question that follows this is, when do US candidates/ incoming politicians/ politicians travel commercial and travel with Government allocates resources?

Comment: Are you aware that "Air Force One" simply designates any USAF flight that bears the president, and that there are two airplanes that are typically used for such flights?

Comment: See for example the use of the adverb "normally" by the Guardian in [Official plane used by Trump will fly to Scotland just before Biden inauguration – report](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/jan/04/trump-biden-inauguration-plane-flight-scotland).

Comment: Yes I was aware of this formality but did not think it was relevant to the question.

Comment: The aircraft used by the vice president is designated [Air Force Two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Two).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do President-elects and Vice-Presidents elects travel?

During the presidential campaign a number of charter jets were used.

A list of the aircraft used by Biden and Harris during the presidential and vice presidential campaigns is provided by JetTip, [Tracking the 2020 US Presidential Campaign Aircraft](https://jettip.net/blog/tracking-the-2020-us-presidential-campaign-aircraft), through November 4, 2020. After the election, the aircraft used by Biden and Harris were "blocked by commercial flight trackers".

It appears that Biden may still be using a 737-500 since it is the only plane painted for the campaign.

Harris may be using a Gulfstream G650.

As for ground transportation, probably Secret Service provided SUVs.

> [W]hen do US candidates/ incoming politicians/ politicians travel commercial and travel with Government allocates resources?

The Speaker of the House, as third in line to the presidency, may choose an ["Air Force C-20B jet that’s normally made available to the House speaker"](https://vpm.org/news/articles/14147/politifact-no-nancy-pelosi-doesnt-demand-to-fly-on-a-200-seat-boeing-757-jet). Otherwise, politicians and candidates provide for their own transportation.